# How to pivot Datetime type implementing checks based on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I want to Pivot the "Person_Log" table data..
Its Columns are as follows:

```
EmployeeID-> Foreign key
Log-> DateTime type
```

format of "Log" is `"1/22/2013 2:02:34 PM"`

I want to create pivots based on checks on Date from Log column and then display the minimum and maximum values for the time on each date...
its a sort of attendance report..
Required columns are like...

```
EmployeeID, 01-Jan IN, 01-Jan OUT, 02-Jan IN, 02-Jan OUT, 03-Jan IN, 03-Jan OUT.....and so on..
```

columns other than the EmployeeID are supposed to contain only time extracted from "Log" column..
For extraction i am using convert(char(10), Log, 101) for Date and convert(char(5), Log, 108) for Time extraction Purpose..

The best i reached for a single day was this:

```
SELECT   dbo.DoorLog.EmployeeID, 
         CONVERT(char(10), 
         MIN(dbo.DoorLog.DateTime), 101) AS Date, 
         CONVERT(char(8), MIN(dbo.DoorLog.DateTime), 108) AS INTime, 
         CONVERT(char(8), MAX(dbo.DoorLog.DateTime), 108) AS OUTTime, 
         dbo.Person.Name, dbo.Person.Department, dbo.Person.Sex, 
         dbo.Person.WorkUnit, 
         dbo.Person.Position
FROM dbo.DoorLog 
INNER JOIN dbo.Person ON dbo.DoorLog.EmployeeID = dbo.Person.EmployeeID
GROUP BY CONVERT(char(10), dbo.DoorLog.DateTime, 101), 
         dbo.DoorLog.EmployeeID, dbo.Person.Name, dbo.Person.Department, 
         dbo.Person.Sex, dbo.Person.WorkUnit, dbo.Person.Position;
```

Please reply as i am running on deadline of two days.. 
Thanks in advance

As u asked...sample data..

```
Log                           EmployeeID 
2013/01/31 12:31              11
2013/01/25 10:31              10
2013/01/23 13:29              8
2013/01/20 11:49              4
```

Comment: can you post your table structure, sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: How many columns must have your result?

Comment: @bluefeet : I have edited the question with the sample data in it..

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: other than employee id the result needs two columns for each day..one showing the in time and other column the out time..
Similary for each day there is a need of two columns for the monthly basis...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data transformation is a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). In SQL Server 2005+ there is a function that will rotate the data for you.  There are a few ways that you can get the result that you want. Both version will implement both the `UNPIVOT` and then the `PIVOT` function.

**Sample Data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Person ([EmployeeId] int, [Name] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO Person  ([EmployeeId], [Name])
VALUES
    (11, 'Jim'),
    (10, 'John'),
    (8, 'Mary'),
    (4, 'Tim');

CREATE TABLE DoorLog([EmployeeId] int, [DoorDate] datetime);

INSERT INTO DoorLog ([EmployeeId], [DoorDate])
VALUES
    (11, '2013-01-31 12:31:00'),
    (11, '2013-01-31 16:50:00'),
    (11, '2013-01-31 17:50:00'),
    (10, '2013-01-25 10:31:00'),
    (10, '2013-01-25 16:45:00'),
    (8, '2013-01-23 13:29:00'),
    (8, '2013-01-23 18:25:00'),
    (4, '2013-01-20 11:49:00'),
    (4, '2013-01-20 19:10:00'),
    (11, '2013-01-15 11:15:00'),
    (11, '2013-01-15 16:25:00'),
    (10, '2013-01-10 09:21:00'),
    (10, '2013-01-10 15:45:00'),
    (8, '2013-01-08 01:29:00'),
    (8, '2013-01-08 02:25:00'),
    (4, '2013-01-06 10:17:00'),
    (4, '2013-01-06 19:10:00');
```

Your query starts with getting the list of employees with the min/max value for each date:

```
select p.employeeid,
  p.name,
  convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101) date,
  min(d.doordate) [In],
  max(d.doordate) [Out]
from person p
left join doorlog d
  on p.employeeid = d.employeeid
group by p.employeeid, p.name, 
  convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb56a/37)

The next step is the `UNPIVOT` which will take the separate columns for IN/OUT time and place them into multiple rows:

```
select employeeid, name, 
      convert(char(8), doortime, 108) DoorTime,
      date + '_'+ col as col_names
from
(
  select p.employeeid,
      p.name,
      convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101) date,
      min(d.doordate) [In],
      max(d.doordate) [Out]
  from person p
  left join doorlog d
      on p.employeeid = d.employeeid
  group by p.employeeid, p.name, 
      convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101)
) src
unpivot
(
  doortime
  for col in ([In], [Out])
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91442/2). The result will look like this:

```
| EMPLOYEEID | NAME | DOORTIME |      COL_NAMES |
-------------------------------------------------
|          4 |  Tim | 10:17:00 |  01/06/2013_In |
|          4 |  Tim | 19:10:00 | 01/06/2013_Out |
|          4 |  Tim | 11:49:00 |  01/20/2013_In |
|          4 |  Tim | 19:10:00 | 01/20/2013_Out |
```

Once you have this result, you can then apply the pivot. If you know the date values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select employeeid, name, 
    convert(char(8), doortime, 108) DoorTime,
    date + '_'+ col as col_names
  from
  (
    select p.employeeid,
      p.name,
      convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101) date,
      min(d.doordate) [In],
      max(d.doordate) [Out]
    from person p
    left join doorlog d
      on p.employeeid = d.employeeid
    group by p.employeeid, p.name, 
      convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101)
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    doortime
    for col in ([In], [Out])
  ) unpiv
) p
pivot
(
  max(doortime)
  for col_names in ([01/06/2013_In], [01/06/2013_Out],
                    [01/08/2013_In], [01/08/2013_Out],
                    [01/10/2013_In], [01/10/2013_Out],
                    [01/15/2013_In], [01/15/2013_Out],
                    [01/20/2013_In], [01/20/2013_Out],
                    [01/23/2013_In], [01/23/2013_Out],
                    [01/31/2013_In], [01/31/2013_Out])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91442/1).

But for your situation you will probably need to use dynamic SQL to generate the result since you will most likely want the results on the fly for any month.  A dynamic SQL version of this is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(date +'_'+Logname) 
                    from
                    (
                      select doordate,
                        convert(char(10),doordate, 101) date, 
                        LogName
                      from DoorLog
                      cross apply
                      (
                        select 'In' LogName
                        union all
                        select 'Out' 
                      ) l
                    ) s   
                    group by convert(char(10), doordate, 112), date, Logname
                    order by convert(char(10), doordate, 112)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
    = 'select employeeid, name, '+@cols+'
       from
       (
         select employeeid, name, 
          convert(char(8), doortime, 108) DoorTime,
          date + ''_''+ col col_names
         from
         (
            select p.employeeid,
              p.name,
              convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101) date,
              min(d.doordate) [In],
              max(d.doordate) [Out]
            from person p
            left join doorlog d
              on p.employeeid = d.employeeid
            group by p.employeeid, p.name, 
              convert(char(10),d.doordate, 101)
         )src
         unpivot
         (
           doortime
           for col in ([In], [Out])
         ) unpiv
       ) p
       pivot
       (
          max(doortime)
          for col_names in('+@cols+')
       ) piv'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb56a/36).

The result of both queries is:

```
| EMPLOYEEID | NAME | 01/06/2013_IN | 01/06/2013_OUT | 01/08/2013_IN | 01/08/2013_OUT | 01/10/2013_IN | 01/10/2013_OUT | 01/15/2013_IN | 01/15/2013_OUT | 01/20/2013_IN | 01/20/2013_OUT | 01/23/2013_IN | 01/23/2013_OUT | 01/25/2013_IN | 01/25/2013_OUT | 01/31/2013_IN | 01/31/2013_OUT |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         11 |  Jim |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      11:15:00 |       16:25:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      12:31:00 |       17:50:00 |
|         10 | John |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      09:21:00 |       15:45:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      10:31:00 |       16:45:00 |        (null) |         (null) |
|          8 | Mary |        (null) |         (null) |      01:29:00 |       02:25:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      13:29:00 |       18:25:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |
|          4 |  Tim |      10:17:00 |       19:10:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |      11:49:00 |       19:10:00 |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |        (null) |         (null) |
```

Comment: Respect :)
really an elaborated and cleanly explained..
let me try this and then will revert..
thanks for your efforts... :)

Comment: THanks... The sql queries are running perfect..
but i m having some problems in using dynamic queries...
i am not clear on how to use dynamic sql to generate result...

Comment: @bluefeet...i have been trying to use this procedure with my code..
but got stuck with a new problem..
hope to seek some help here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585210/conversion-failed-when-converting-datetime-from-character-string