# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, windows

I am trying to pass parameters from windows application to a stored procedure.
there are two parameters '@dt' & '@dt2' which get value from datetimepickers.
whenever i execute the stored procedure it comes up with the error saying "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

After executing the query i want to display it in a datagridview.

i am unable to figure out the problem..
here is my procedure and code

Stored Procedure

> ALTER proc [dbo].[deepak_proc]
>
> ( @dt datetime, @dt2 datetime )
>
> AS
>
> declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
>
> declare @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
>
> select @cols =
>
> ```
>               STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(date +'_'+Logname) 
>                 from
>                 (
>                   select K_date,
>                     convert(char(10),K_date, 101) date, 
>                     LogName
>                   from kq_report_analyze
>                   cross apply
>                   (
>                     select 'In' LogName
>                     union all
>                     select 'Out' 
>                   ) l
>                 ) s   
>                 group by convert(char(10), K_date, 112), date, Logname
>                 order by convert(char(10), K_date, 112)
>         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
>     ,1,1,'')
> ```
>
> set @query
>
> ```
> = 'SELECT empid, name, status, '+@cols+' FROM (SELECT empid, name, status, 
>    doortime, date + "_" + col AS col_names FROM  (SELECT k_userid
>    AS [empid], K_Name AS name, k_description1 as [status], K_WorktimeUp1
>    AS [IN], K_WorktimeDown1 AS OUT, CONVERT(char(10), K_Date, 101) AS
>   date FROM  dbo.kq_report_analyze WHERE (K_Date BETWEEN '+@dt+' AND
>   '+@dt2+') GROUP BY K_UserID, K_Name, k_description1, K_Date,
>   K_WorktimeUp1, K_WorktimeDown1) src  UNPIVOT (doortime FOR col IN
>   ([IN], [OUT])) unpiv) 
>   p PIVOT (max(doortime) FOR col_names IN ('+@cols+')) piv;'
> ```
>
> execute(@query)

And the following code is on button click

> SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
>   con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test_db;User ID=user;Password=password";
>
> ```
>      con.Open();
>
>
>        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("deepak_proc", con);
>
>
>    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
> ```
>
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
>
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
>
> DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>
> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>
> sda.Fill(dt);
>
> dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
>
> con.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) system stored procedure and put your variables as parametrs

```
SET @query
= 'SELECT empid, name, status, ' + @cols + ' 
   FROM (SELECT empid, name, status, doortime, date + ''_'' + col AS col_names 
         FROM  (SELECT k_userid AS [empid], K_Name AS name, 
                       k_description1 as [status], K_WorktimeUp1 AS [IN], 
                       ktimeDown1 AS OUT, CONVERT(char(10), K_Date, 101) AS date 
                FROM  dbo.kq_report_analyze 
                WHERE (K_Date BETWEEN @dt AND @dt2) 
                GROUP BY K_UserID, K_Name, k_description1, K_Date, K_WorktimeUp1,
                         K_WorktimeDown1) src  
   UNPIVOT (doortime FOR col IN ([IN], [OUT])) unpiv) p 
   PIVOT (max(doortime) FOR col_names IN (' + @cols + ')) piv;'

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@dt datetime, @dt2 datetime', @dt, @dt2
```

Comment: @alexander...dint made any difference...error is still the same.. :/

Comment: @alexander...well atleast the parameters got passed.. :)
but the result is not as per expected...so will be working a little longer on this thing.. :/

thanks for ur help... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the datetime into the yyyy-MM-dd format which is standard.

Comment: @Haedrian... i have been using the mm/dd/yyyy format on both the application and sqlserver end.
Will there be any difference if i'll change the date format on both the ends?

Comment: You don't need to change the format on the SQL end. But yyyy-MM-dd is a standard culture-independant format, so it'll work regardless of date/time culture settings. I'm just assuming that its having some ambigous issues parsing MM/dd/yyyy .

Comment: I'm talking about internal use here. If you format it in MM/dd/yyyy for your users to see its allright.

Comment: Can you debug it to see what string EXACTLY you're passing it? Also is it a date or a datetime SQL side?

Comment: @haedrian...Its datetime on both side..but i am converting it into date  , as u can see in the query..
error is in execution of query .. but how do i  check the exact string  i am passing..

Comment: Put a breakpoint right before you pass the parameter, then use watch to see the value.

Comment: @haedrian... parameters passed are in format yyyy/mm/dd..
One more thing.when i execute only the query within my code with the parameteres '@dt' & '@dt2' then the results are as expected.
but i m not been able to figure out the problem with the stored procedure..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though you're getting a string representation of a date from the DateTimepicker in the client. When you get the value from the DateTimepicker, convert it to a bona fide CLR Date object *client-side*. Don't pass strings to the back-end if there is a CLR type that maps to the SQL type. Choose the appropriate parameter type when building the command object client-side.

**In general, keep dates as dates and convert them to strings only when you need to display them for human eyes.**

Edit:
For example:

```
        SqlClient.SqlParameter  p0;

        p0.ParameterName = "@startdate";
        p0.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        p0.Value =  < a datetime object, not a string>  
        p0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Then add the parameter to the Parameters collection.

Comment: @tim...tried and still the same error...

 System.DateTime mydate = default(System.DateTime);
 mydate =  dateTimePicker1.Value;
 System.DateTime mydate1 = default(System.DateTime);
 mydate1 = dateTimePicker2.Value;


created these two datetime variables and assigned to the '@dt' & '@dt2'..
still the same error..

Comment: may be i am doing something wrong here...please guide me in a proper direction..thanks for the help..

Comment: You are passing strings to the sp.  You want to pass datetime.

Comment: @tim... in the last edit, as u suggested i did passed the values directly without any conversion..
did i missed something, or am i doing wrong?

Comment: No you didn't. You're doing toString()

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter
("@myDateTime", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime));
 cmd.Parameters["@myDateTime"].Value = myDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =DateTime.ParseExact( dateTimePicker1.Value.Tostring(),null);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimePicker2.Value.Tostring(),null);